# Build succeeds but black screen

Tags: iphone, xcode

The build process is fine but then i get a black screen. I tried putting a breakpoint in the app delegate but it doesn't seem to run.

What could it be?

This is my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //Init Airship launch options
    NSMutableDictionary *takeOffOptions = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
    [takeOffOptions setValue:launchOptions forKey:UAirshipTakeOffOptionsLaunchOptionsKey];

    // Create Airship singleton that's used to talk to Urban Airship servers.
    // Please populate AirshipConfig.plist with your info from http://go.urbanairship.com
    [UAirship takeOff:takeOffOptions];
    // Register for notifications
    [[UAPush shared] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |                                UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
    (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

    usersData = [PlayersData sharedInstance];
    //[usersData cleanUserDefauts];  // --- use to clean user defaults

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.loadingPageVC = [[LoadingPage alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoadingPage" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.loadingPageVC;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];



    ConnectionManager *connectionManager = [ConnectionManager sharedInstance];
    NSLog(@"Connection statement: %@",[connectionManager checkConnection]);
    if ([[connectionManager checkConnection] isEqualToString:@"connected with wifi"] || [[connectionManager checkConnection] isEqualToString:@"connected with wwan"] ) {
    [connectionManager getLocation];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: you need to restart xcode

Comment: Can you show your `AppDelegate`'s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method? Probably there might be a mistake in that.

Comment: Yeah as Goti said, try with didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.  Try a NSLog or breakpoint from there.  If not Remove the contents of /Library/Caches/ folder and relaunch Xcode.

Comment: will you put breakpoint in supporting files->main.m ?

Comment: Ok, i tried cleaning, restarting Xcode, restarting the simulator and when none worked i restarted my computer… Also with no success.

Comment: I just added my didFinishLaunching method

Comment: Does any warning appear in the log window? When u run the app with a black screen?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes(Very Rarely) XCode can behave different.If something is really weird i would do the following things.

1. Do a clean build
2. Remove your app in the Simulator and Build Again
3. Restart Simulator and Build Again
4. Close XCode and Reopen it
5. Worst case is to restart the System

Answer (score 0):

No need to resart anything. Just follow a step given below & you will achieve what you want.

```
 1. Go to /Users/<MAC_NAME>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<SIMULATOR_VERSION>, delete all & run app
```

Enjoy Programming!

Comment: I tried that, but then when i click play it builds and immediately  stops

Comment: do you want to create .app or .ipa?

Comment: right now, i just want to test my app. IPA is not needed now.

Comment: does your simulator get pops up?

Comment: What do you mean by pop ups? Didn't try anything like it

Comment: Ok, i just found out it is something to do with the app itself. i tried running a different app and it works

Comment: when you click on run button from xcode, simulator will load within 2/3 second as soon as the app loads, & gets appear in front of xcode? Does anything like this happen with your simulator?

Comment: Thank :) but I still don't know what it is… Could it get stuck due to a code before it reads it?

Comment: it must be some problem with the app itself. To know the exact reason behind this, I need to check the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have changed your xib name from  `ViewController` to `LoadingPage`.

If so, then you must have to delegate it from your .xib. From the top-right corner. Like,

[image]

I have just given my opinion that this may be your solution. If you have succeeded with another one, let me know.....:)

Comment: That is an old part of my project that is working for a few months now :) That is not the problem

Answer (score 0):

Ok! This is solved.

Apparently someone I work with changed one simple word and that messed everything up…

He made the `appDelegate` inherit from `UIApplication` instead from `UIResponder`.

Now it works.